# Change architecture of panda dataframe (index - column)

Tags: python, pandas

First of all, this is my first question in StackOverflow, then tell me if i do something wrong (and sorry for my english, i'am french people :) ).

This question is to find the best method to change dataframe architecture, in Python script.

This is what i have (dataframe):

```
    Name    Point    LoadCase    Data1    Data2    Data3
0   Name1   point1   LC1         1        2        4
1   NA      NA       NA          5        6        7
2   NA      TOTAL    NA          8        9        10
3   Name1   point1   LC2         11       12       13
4   NA      NA       NA          14       15       16
5   NA      TOTAL    NA          17       18       19
6   Name2   point2   LC1         20       21       22      
7   NA      NA       NA          23       24       25
8   NA      TOTAL    NA          26       27       28
9   Name2   point2   LC2         29       30       31
10  NA      NA       NA          32       33       34
11  NA      TOTAL    NA          35       36       37
```

And this, is what i want (results for TOTAL row, but with points id)

```
    Name    Point    Data    LC1    LC2
0   Name1   Point1   Data1   8      17
1   Name1   Point1   Data2   9      18
2   Name1   Point1   Data3   10     19
3   Name2   Point2   Data1   26     35
4   Name2   Point2   Data2   27     36
5   Name2   Point2   Data3   28     37
```

To do this, i try several things but no one work for me (or i did not manage to make them work), i try with stack() function, and multiIndex function of dataframe.

If you have any idea for help me, please share it with me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the values of `NA` of type `str` or `numpy.nan`?

Comment: The dataframe is build from csv file. The NA values corresponding to empty data in csv file. The exact values is NaN, and i think is numpy.nan, but not sure, i will check this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a boolean column to track which rows are the "TOTAL" rows, cleanup and forward fill the "Point", and then melt and pivot the data.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['is_total'] = df.Point.eq('TOTAL')
df['Point'] = df.Point.replace('TOTAL', np.nan)

out = (df.ffill()
         .query('is_total')
         .drop('is_total', axis=1)
         .melt(id_vars=['Name', 'Point', 'LoadCase'], var_name='Data')
         .pivot_table(index=['Name', 'Point', 'Data'], columns='LoadCase')
      )
out.columns = out.columns.get_level_values(-1)
out = out.reset_index()
out
# returns:
LoadCase   Name   Point   Data  LC1  LC2
0         Name1  point1  Data1    8   17
1         Name1  point1  Data2    9   18
2         Name1  point1  Data3   10   19
3         Name2  point2  Data1   26   35
4         Name2  point2  Data2   27   36
5         Name2  point2  Data3   28   37
```

Comment: I still have error. As my panda version is 0.19, i have to change the melt syntaxe, then i try this : 
` 
df['is_total'] = df.Point.eq('TOTAL')
df['Point'] = df.Point.replace('TOTAL', np.nan)
out = (df.ffill()
     .query('is_total')
     .drop('is_total', axis=1)
out1 = pd.melt(out, id_vars=['Name', 'Point', 'LoadCase'], var_name='Data')
out1.pivot_table(index=['Name', 'Point', 'Data'], columns='LoadCase')
out1.columns = out1.columns.get_level_values(-1)
out1 = out1.reset_index()`
But i still have column of Load case, and not 1 column for each load case.
I did something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some `.loc` filtering, `ffill` and then `melt` with `groupby` followed by `unstack`

```
df.loc[df['Point'].eq('TOTAL'),'var'] = 'Total'
df['Point'] = df['Point'].replace('TOTAL',np.nan).ffill()

df1 = df.ffill().loc[df["var"].eq("Total")].drop("var", axis=1).melt(
    id_vars=["Name", "Point", "LoadCase"]
).groupby(["Name", "Point", "LoadCase", "variable"]).first().unstack("LoadCase").reset_index()

print(df1)

           Name   Point variable value    
LoadCase                           LC1 LC2
0         Name1  point1    Data1     8  17
1         Name1  point1    Data2     9  18
2         Name1  point1    Data3    10  19
3         Name2  point2    Data1    26  35
4         Name2  point2    Data2    27  36
5         Name2  point2    Data3    28  37
```

Comment: Thansk for yourn answers, it seems to be working. But you know if it possible to put this dataframe into csv with the columns like : Name-Point-variable-LC1-LC2, instead of Name-point-variable-value ?